# I can't access WordPress admin page

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to get into `wp-admin` page of my wordpress website these warnings come up:

> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../../wp-includes/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/opt/awex-pages:/storage/ssd4/476/999476) in /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-editor.php on line 17
>
> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../../../wp-includes/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/opt/awex-pages:/storage/ssd4/476/999476) in /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-editor.php on line 20
>
> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../../wp-includes/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/opt/awex-pages:/storage/ssd4/476/999476) in /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-editor.php on line 29
>
> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../../../wp-includes/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/opt/awex-pages:/storage/ssd4/476/999476) in /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-editor.php on line 32
>
> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../../wp-load.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/opt/awex-pages:/storage/ssd4/476/999476) in /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-editor.php on line 44
>
> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../../../wp-load.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/opt/awex-pages:/storage/ssd4/476/999476) in /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-editor.php on line 47
>
> Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-editor.php on line 70
>
> Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-editor.php on line 73
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-editor.php:17) in /storage/ssd4/476/999476/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210`

How do I get back the admin page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have activated a plugin which is causing this error.

Log into your CPanel and navigate to `wp-content/plugins`.

Change the names of all the plugin directories or if you remember the last plugin you installed or activated after which the issue occurred; in that case, change the name of that plugin directory.

This will deactivate the plugin/s. Try accessing your `wp-admin` now. If you can access it, start to correct the names you changed of the plugin directories. This will allow you to pin-point the plugin causing the issue.